# How to check if any of the strings from an array with variable length are present in another string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter some data from an array in a JSON file, based on an input of the form `string1`, `string1,string2`, `string1,string2,string3` etc., that is, some strings separated by a `,`.

What I'm trying to do:

```
let arrInput = document.getElementById('inputBox').val.split(',');

for(let i = 0; i < arrToFilter.length; i++){
    if(.........what to write here?...........){
        arrOutput.push(arrToFilter[i]);
    }
}

return arrOutput;
```

If the `arrInput` had a fixed length, I could accomplish this using `indexOf != -1` for each element in `arrInput`, but here, since the length of `arrInput` is variable, how can I check if at least one of the strings present in `arrInput` is also present as a substring in `arrToFIlter[i]`?

**Edit:**

Example:

Let `arrToFilter` be `["abcqwer", "pizza", "definition", "abcdef", "example"]`

**Case 1 :**

Say the input entered (in an `<input>` element) is `abc,def`.

For this, the `arrOutput` should be `["abcqwer", "definition", "abcdef"]`

**Case 2:**

Say the input entered is `abc`

Expected output : `["abcqwer", "abcdef"]`

Comment: What is your desired result, True/False or something else?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please add a clear example of what you try to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: `arrInput.includes(arrToFilter[i])`?

Comment: @WilliamLohan Please see the edit for an example. I don't think it'll work if I want to check if say "abcdef"(`arrToFilter[i]`) has "abc" or "def"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is using some and filter,

```js
var string = 'ad,kk,sb';
var array = ['adik', 'klop', 'pp'];

var stringers = string.split(',');
var result = array.filter((arr) => {
    var isPresent = stringers.some(stringer => arr.includes(stringer));
    return isPresent ? true : false;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please see the edit, as I don't think this code will give the desired result if I have one of the elements in `array` as `'klmn'`. Thanks!

Comment: Editted according to your criteria.

Comment: @Eagle we can simply do using filter and some.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate both arrays

```
let arrToFilter = ['abcqwer', 'pizza', 'definition', 'abcdef', 'example'];
let arrOutput = [];
let arrInput = document.getElementById('inputBox').value.split(',');

arrToFilter.forEach(filter => {
  arrInput.forEach(input => {
    if (!!input && filter.includes(input)) {
      arrOutput.push(filter);
    }
  });
});
//                      distinct the output
return arrOutput.filter((v, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(v));
```